# hi there, i need this regex in php

Tags: php, regex

i have dynamic string like following things:

```
ASD_3498dfknsdf
23423_askdjkl23493204
x_2394dslfk
BBDF34_kasjdkasldj
```

in this situation, i need get this outputs:

```
ASD
23423
x
BBDF34
```

so, i have to get part of string before underscore.

Thanks so much for your helps.

Comment: Why a regex? Just find the first occurrence of `'_'` and cut there

Comment: you can use explode it through `_`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you know, when you tell others to do your work, you might as well tell them _how_ they should do your work ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak naa, I think they can go from there without me holding their hand, as it is quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $str = '23423_askdjkl23493204';
 preg_match("/\w+(\_)/", $str, $matches);
 $test =str_replace("_", '', $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

YOu can simply do this by exploding the string by underscore and then take the 0th index of the array like this:

```
  $str='test_12334';
  $str_to_arr=explode('_',$str);
  $char_before_underscore=$str_to_arr['0'];
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap the `0` in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex. This is a valid case to use [`strstr`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
echo strstr("23423_askdjkl23493204", "_", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your super response.